# Publish-PSArtifactUtility cannot resolve module dependency when publishing even when they are in the same feed

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to publish a PowerShell module to Azure Artifacts which has a dependency on another module that is hosted in the same Artifacts feed. The idea is that when I install the module locally from the feed, the correct version of the dependency is installed automatically. The problem is that when I run:

```
Publish-Module -NuGetApiKey "{token}" -Path {path} -Repository "{ArtifactsFeedName}" -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
```

I get the following error:

```
 Publish-PSArtifactUtility : PowerShellGet cannot resolve the module dependency '{dependency}' of the module 
 '{moduleWhichHasDependency}' on the repository '{ArtifactsFeed}'. Verify that the dependent module '{dependency}' 
 is available in the repository '{ArtifactsFeed}'. If this dependent module '{dependency}' is managed externally, 
 add it to the ExternalModuleDependencies entry in the PSData section of the module manifest.
 At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1190 char:17
 +                 Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSModuleInfo $moduleInfo `
 +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Publish-PSArtifactUtility], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToResolveModuleDependency,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
```

In the manifest, the dependency is added like this:

```
 RequiredModules = @( @{ModuleName = '{dependency}'; ModuleVersion = '1.0.4'; })
```

Then I tried adding:

```
ExternalModuleDependencies = @( @{ModuleName = '{dependency}'; ModuleVersion = '1.0.4'; })
```

The module is published but when I install it locally, it doesn't install the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to have been fixed in the latest version of PowershellGet (2.2 in the PSGallery, version installed on my computer was 1.0.1).
You could also install the latest version of PackageManagement (1.4.3 vs 1.0.1)

See :

Added credential parameter to subsequent calls of Publish-Module/Script. #93 
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/pull/93

Implement Publish-Module credential parameter propagation to sub-functions #104 
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/pull/104

To do this :

```
Install-Module PowershellGet -Force #-Scope Current #if you don't want to login as Administrator
```

However, I have a question for you : how do you manage not to give your Credentials when you call Publish-Module with an Azure Artifact feed ? I know they should be stored in the file nuget.config but I have to give them each time.

```
Publish-Module -NuGetApiKey "{whatever}" -Credentials "{PSCredentials object}" -Path {path} -Repository "{ArtifactsFeedName}" -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
```

Answer (score 1):

expanding on @clientGOOG answer, my version was 2.2.4.1 but i had the same issue, i am publishing to myget and i solved this problem by using a pre-authenticated thread. I did **not** have to add ExternalModuleDependencies settings to make this work.

With the -Verbose flag I noticed that the "find" process was retrying 3x before giving up.

```
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: Using the specified source names : '{myrepo}'.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://{myorg}.myget.org/F/{myfeed}/api/v3/index.json' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://{myorg}.myget.org/F/{myfeed}/api/v3/index.json' for '2' more times
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://{myorg}.myget.org/F/{myfeed}/api/v3/index.json' for '1' more times
VERBOSE: Retry downloading 'https://{myorg}.myget.org/F/{myfeed}/api/v3/index.json' for '0' more times
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'0' for the specified package '{dependent module}'.
```

Here is my revised code that solved the issue:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name {MyRepo} "https://{myorg}.myget.org/F/{myfeed}/auth/{apikey}/api/v2"

Publish-Module -Path ($module.path |Split-Path -Parent) -NuGetApiKey $APIKey -Repository {MyRepo} -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
```

**Note:** it still required the NuGetApiKey on the publish but the authenticated feed i would assume is passed down to the "find" call that is failing which is why it now works.